# Error(14,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle 18c express edition below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETTOP15CLIENTS
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  
        customerId NUMBER;
        totalOrders NUMBER;
    BEGIN

    SELECT C.customer_id, COUNT(O.order_id) INTO customerId, totalOrders 
    FROM CUSTOMERS C
    JOIN ORDERS O ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
    GROUP BY C.customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(O.order_id) > 15
    ORDER BY COUNT(O.order_id) DESC

    END;
END;
```

but I am getting the following errors

> Error(8,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Error(14,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> Error(15,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

This is my very first time in Oracle.Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: semi-colon is missing at the end of the select statement. Moreover remove `BEGIN
 DECLARE` at the beginning along with one of `END`s at the end.

Comment: The semi-colon missing at the end of the SELECT statements is the immediate cause of the error. Other than that, why are you using a nested block within the procedure? That is not illegal, but it seems unnecessary. Moreover, you will run into a new error if the SELECT query returns more than one row (more than one "group" with count greater than 15): you want to select INTO scalar variables, and that will fail if the query returns multiple rows.